# html() function issue

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to parse JSON with jQuery, but I have some problem with it. I want to get JSON link.

```
const data = $.html(function(){
  const entities = Entities.decode((this).toString());
  const obj = JSON.parse(entities);
  return {
    url: obj.url
  }
}).get();
console.log(data)
```

Result:

> $.html(...).get is not a function

Code i'm trying to parse:

```
{&quot;url&quot;: &quot;http://download2018.com/ap/_com.GloftGGHM_2018-05-25.apk?X-Amz-Algorithm=AWS4-HMAC-SHA256&amp;X-Amz-Credential=IFVYHACUO60QSGWW9L9Z%2F20180622%2Fus-east-1%2Fs3%2Faws4_request&amp;X-Amz-Date=20180622T145015Z&amp;X-Amz-Expires=2400&amp;X-Amz-SignedHeaders=host&amp;X-Amz-Signature=4bcec8896510ede49eb7150d684274fcefb47c036c82e852a316125b1fbdd742&quot;, &quot;resp&quot;: &quot;success&quot;}
```

I'll appreciate your help !

Comment: The `html()` method is meant to be used to get/set the innerHTML on elements ( http://api.jquery.com/html/ ). Your attempted usage of it is confusing me.  What exactly are you trying to do?

Comment: How do you end up with HTML encoded JSON?  What do you want as an end result? Plaint text JSON or an object?

Comment: @taplar I'm trying to get url from code, but i can't use html() with elements or attribute, because it's encoded, i'm was trying to do it with .map, but it dont work to. my main point to get link in JSON but idk how to get it with encoded JSON

Comment: @AlexK. so how i can get result with my encoded JSON ? without .html()

Comment: `x = JSON.parse($("<div/>").html(html_encoded_json_string).text()).url;` assumnig there are no urlencoding/htmlencoding issues in the original.

Comment: @AlexK. if that works, that sounds like an answer, :)

Comment: @AlexK. yes, but my code don't have any "<div/>" so it gives me this : `Malformed attribute selector` or `Unexpected token o in JSON at position 1`

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/alexk/0aufngdr/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem you have is caused by the fact that the JSON has been HTML encoded. To parse it back to an object you will need to first HTML decode it, which you can do using jQuery's `html()` and `text()` methods, like this:

```js
var htmlEncodedJSON = "{&quot;url&quot;: &quot;http://download2018.com/ap/_com.GloftGGHM_2018-05-25.apk?X-Amz-Algorithm=AWS4-HMAC-SHA256&amp;X-Amz-Credential=IFVYHACUO60QSGWW9L9Z%2F20180622%2Fus-east-1%2Fs3%2Faws4_request&amp;X-Amz-Date=20180622T145015Z&amp;X-Amz-Expires=2400&amp;X-Amz-SignedHeaders=host&amp;X-Amz-Signature=4bcec8896510ede49eb7150d684274fcefb47c036c82e852a316125b1fbdd742&quot;, &quot;resp&quot;: &quot;success&quot;}";

var $el = $('<div />').html(htmlEncodedJSON);
var obj = JSON.parse($el.text())

console.log(obj.resp); // individual property 
console.log(obj); // full object
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Note that this is not the ideal solution. The best solution would be to not HTML encode the JSON that's coming back from the server.

Comment: yes but i have only encoded HTML, so i should work with it (

Comment: If you can't control the server response, then that's your only choice, sadly.